# firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

[[image: This is the database]]

```
firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
```

I am trying to add this data to a FirebaserecyclerAdapter and getting this error

Here is the database reference

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions");
```

this is how I have used the RecyclerViewAdapter

```
  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<History, HistoryViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<History, HistoryViewHolder>(
            History.class, R.layout.history_list_item, HistoryViewHolder.class, databaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(HistoryViewHolder viewHolder, History model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setMyanswer(model.getMyAnswer());
            viewHolder.setCorrentAnswer(model.getCorrectAnswer());
            viewHolder.setImageUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getImageUrl());

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two nodes in your database indeed have a mismatch of data type :

```
myAnswer : "21"
myAnswer : 11
```

If you want this to be a String, it should instead be :

```
myAnswer : "21"
myAnswer : "11"
```

Or, have them as long :

```
myAnswer : 21
myAnswer : 11
```

Make sure you take care of consistency while adding data

Comment: you are number1

Comment: Is it possible to automatically typecast to string ?

Comment: @Killer As far as I know, Firebase has no such provision

Comment: I was using same property name for different classes' different variables. So it causes a cast exception. When I changed the property names of variables it is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
valueX = 21.4;

valueY = 23.5;
```

Need to change Long to String

```
String mValuex = String.valueOf(valueX);

String mValuey = String.valueOf(valueY);

myRef.child(username).child("valuex").setValue(mValuex);

myRef.child(username).child("valuey").setValue(mValuey);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, when creating your DB, specify that the two fields are Strings, either put the figures is double quotes or select String next to the [Select data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPXpy.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).